# Case statement with four different condition in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I’ve an input table and expected output table as attached. ID is string. I want to get the output for Four conditions:

(1) When portfolio =”TR” and ID in (“4572119”, “4886788”) then Conv_out= Conv,

(2) for all other ID and portfolio= “TR”, then Conv_out=0

(3) for all other portfolio, then Conv_out=Conv

(4) When Channel =”Search” then Conv_out= 0.5*Conv, otherwise

Conv_out=Conv for other channel and protfolio

Please assist me. Here is my example code.ID is string data type. The problem is, I'm getting everything correct as I expected except Conv_out is not coming as half when Channel = "Search"

```
(Case when Portfolio in ("TR") and ID in (“4572119”, “4886788”) then Conv
 when Portfolio in ("TR") then 0 
 when Channel = "Search" then Conv/2
 else Conv end) as Conv_out
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhkcX.png)

Comment: shouldn't you move third `when ... then ...` up to be the first one?

Comment: @Mikhali, can you please edit the code, I am kind of stuck on it.

Comment: @ Mikhali, If I follow the order that I mentioned i got the result but it is twice as my expected result. If I change the order as you suggested, I got much more value than I got previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to think about what you expect to be returned if Channel is Search, but Portfolio is TR? Since you're analyzing data by different attributes (portfolio and channel), you may need either correct order of when..then, or additional conditions to be satisfied to reduce ambiguity.

```
CASE
    WHEN Channel = "Search" THEN Conv/2
    WHEN Portfolio = "TR" and ID not in (“4572119”, “4886788”) THEN 0
    ELSE Conv
END
```

Comment: If Channel = Search, then Conv_out= Conv/2 for all portfolio. when Portfolio in ("TR") and ID in (“4572119”, “4886788”) then Conv, but I'd to get  Conv_out= Conv/2 when Channel = Search and Portfolio= "TR".